Demand Forecasting on many items
I have a data about demand of each item in 1 store. For example, a dataframe contains         ['unique_id', 'timestamp', 'is_public_holiday', 'is_long_weekend',
'is_first_day_long_weekend', 'promotion_duration',
'num_promotion_product', 'num_active_promotion', 'apply_promotion',
'profit_margin', 'unit_retail', 'price_change',
'promotion_discount_percentage', 'reward_template_id',
'target_population_type', 'demand', 'pma_cat_sub_code'] . I want to predict the demand on each day by using LSTM but many example i already saw using timestamp as index.
So how could i do since the timestamp maybe the same? (many items sales in one day)
